# What are current PCB surface protection techniques?

Tags: pcb

What are the different tinning techniques for PCBs, and what are the advantages of one technique over the other?

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is that you should look at the options your board house offers and then research that.

Common options I've seen are:

- HASL, Hot Air Solder Leveling: They bascially coat the entire board in solder and use a air knife to blow the excess off, it's cheap but it can leave a slightly uneven surface, which might mean something if you are doing BGAs.
- OSP, Organic Solderability Preservatives: A very thin coating that keeps oxygen away and evaporates when soldering, it looks as though there is just bare copper on the board.

This page has a good description of these and other finishings:
http://www.multicircuits.com/pcb/tech/surface_finishes.html

Answer (score 1):

Immersion silver seems to be getting popular for RoHS boards. It gives a very flat surface, and is fine if boards are soldered quickly. Some companies use immersion gold, even on low-cost boards. Silver can oxidise over time, which apparently can affect solderability, so gold might be better if boards are to be stored. I've had no problems hand-soldering boards finished with both immersion silver and immersion gold (lead solder), and neither has the company I use sometimes for surface-mount board assembly, using lead-free solder paste.

Gold plating has been used on connector pins for years, and has never caused soldering problems.

Comment: Silver surprises me. We once had a batch of boards which were accidentally *completely* gold finished, and I found them impossible to solder, at least by hand, but I think reflow wouldn't have worked either. Gold has a melting temperature over 1000°C (silver is not much less), and soldering occurs at temperatures around 300°C.

Comment: @myself :-) - Apparently there's a binary eutectic Ag alloy with a low melting point, but it's Ag-Pb, so wouldn't be RoHS compliant.

Comment: I've tried to solder (lead-tin) on a gold plated connector, but the solder refused to flow over the gold. Maybe because gold on a connector is thicker than the immersion gold.

Comment: @federico - thickness has nothing to do with it. Below the melting point the material is not permeable for the solder, even when only a few tens of atoms thick. Soldering is a metallurgical process. I don't understand how it can work for Leon.

Comment: @stevenvh - You can solder to copper - which melts at 1085°C

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - Yeah, that crossed my mind just now too. I don't know why there's this difference between gold and copper. They have almost the same melting point, and also their crystal structure is the same (cubic close-packed).

Comment: As I said, I've had absolutely no problems with silver or gold coatings. I use Metcal equipment, perhaps that helps. :)

Comment: @Leon - yes, that's what you told me. For me it doesn't work: the solder forms a drop which seems to be repelled by the gold; it never starts flowing. The only explanation I can think of is that the immersion gold is actually an alloy. I don't think the equipment is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work that I did in recent years have called for [ENIG - Electroless nickel immersion gold.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroless_nickel_immersion_gold)  The plating comes out nice and flat, which is not the case with HASL.  It also looks pretty, but that's a subjective thing.  :)